# WebRTC Black screen while flipping the camera on Android device

Tags: android, camera, ionic2, webrtc

I am using ionic 2 with webrtc to get a video stream from both front and rear camera.

Please see my typescript code below:

```
if (this.isFrontCam) {
  constraints = {
    mandatory: {},
    optional: [{sourceId: this.cameras[0]}]
  };
} else {
  constraints = {
    mandatory: {},
    optional: [{sourceId: this.cameras[1]}]
  };
}


if (this.currentVideoStream && this.currentVideoStream !=null) {
      this.currentVideoStream.getTracks().forEach(function (track) {
        track.stop();
      });
      this.currentVideoStream.release();
      this.currentVideoStream = null;
    }



 var n = <any>navigator;
    n.getUserMedia = n.getUserMedia || n.webkitGetUserMedia || n.mozGetUserMedia || n.msGetUserMedia;

    //getting local video stream
    n.getUserMedia({
      audio: true,
      video: constraints
    }, function (myStream) {
      alert("Current Video stream " + self.currentVideoStream);
      self.currentVideoStream = myStream;
      alert("New Stream"+ myStream);
      //displaying local video stream on the page
      (<HTMLVideoElement>document.getElementById('localVideo')).src = window.URL.createObjectURL(myStream);
```

I am getting 2 different (front and rear) cameras device ids (`this.cameras`)  and if I use them individually both cameras are working as expected but when I flip them using the above code(button click from UI calls this function) like above they are not working. It simply shows black screen.

Comment: I have a couple of thoughts but haven't tested this myself.

1. Have you tried creating a new video element each time?
2. Have you tried calling videoElement.play() after you set the src?
3. Have you tried using srcObject instead of src. This is the new spec. So:

(<HTMLVideoElement>document.getElementById('localVideo')).src = myStream;

Instead of using window.URL.createObjectURL which is the old way.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I was part of hackathon so I need the answer as soon as possible so I used the word urgent because i need the answer within hours so that i can complete remaining part of the code in a day. I use the above code along with webrtc for video chat  on android device. I have even upvoted the comment given by adam. So, i really needed it urgent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by removing the below 2 lines:

```
this.currentVideoStream.release();
this.currentVideoStream = null;
```

and adding `(<HTMLVideoElement>document.getElementById('localVideo')).play();`